# Creating a recursive function with async / await with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a process in my code where I need to get a list of technician drive times.  I use the `Google Maps API` to get the driving time between the origin and destination.  As most of you know, the API requires to have a timeout of roughly 1 second or more to work without generating errors.  I have created a recursive function to retrieve the list of times that I need using a `setTimeout` within the method, like so:

```
function GetTechDriveTimes(info, destAddress) {
  let techs = this.state.Techs
    .filter(tech => tech.Address != "" && !tech.Notes.includes('Not'))
    .map(tech => {
      let techObj = {
        TechName: tech.FirstName + " " + tech.LastName,
        TechAddress: tech.Address + " " + tech.City + " " + tech.State + " " + tech.Zip,
        KioskID: info.ID.toUpperCase(),
        DriveTime: "",
      };
      return techObj
    });

  let temp = [...techs]; // create copy of techs array

  const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  recursion();
  let count = 0;

  function recursion() {
    const techAddress = temp.shift(); // saves first element and removes it from array
    directionsService.route({
      origin: techAddress.TechAddress,
      destination: destAddress,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }, function (res, status) {
      if (status == 'OK') {
        let time = res.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
        techs[count].DriveTime = time;
      } else {
        console.log(status);
      }
      if (temp.length) {  // if length of array still exists
        count++;
        setTimeout(recursion, 1000);
      } else {
        console.log('DONE');
      }
    });
  }

  return techs;
}
```

After this method is complete, it will return an array with the techs and their respective drive times to that destination.  The problem here is that using `setTimeout` obviously doesn't stop execution of the rest of my code, so returning the array of technicians will just return the array with empty drive times.
After timeout is complete I want it to return the array within the method it was called like this:

```
function OtherMethod() {
 // there is code above this to generate info and destAddress

 let arr = GetTechDriveTimes(info, destAddress);

 // other code to be executed after GetTechDriveTimes()
}
```

I've looked online for something like this, and it looks like I would need to use a `Promise` to accomplish this, but the difference from what I found online is that they weren't using it inside of a recursive method.  If anyone has any ideas, that would help me a lot.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use promises, but you can also create a callback with the "other code to be executed after GetTechDriveTimes" and send it to the function:

```
function OtherMethod() {
  // there is code above this to generate info and destAddress

  // instead of arr = GetTechDriveTimes, let arr be the parameter of the callback
  GetTechDriveTimes(info, destAddress, function(arr) {
    // other code to be executed after GetTechDriveTimes()
  });
}

function GetTechDriveTimes(info, destAddress, callback) {
  ...

    if (temp.length) {  // if length of array still exists
      ...
    } else {
      console.log('DONE');
      callback(techs); // send the result as the parameter
    }

  ...
```

Comment: I will have to try this out.  Will this actually wait until that callback is called before executing the code after it?

Comment: this works, but would it be possible to ```await``` the callback before executing the other code, instead of putting it all inside that method?

Comment: Yes you could, please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises